# Syntax error with python list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a python list of integers with `0` and `1`, now I want to change `0` to `-1`, so I'm doing this:

```
[v[i] = -1 for i in range(len(v)) if v[i] == 0]
```

then I get `syntax error`. what's wrong with this?

I also tried the map + lambda but still not working.

```
map(lambda x: -1 if x == 0 else x, v)
```

this time it's not syntax error but just didn't change anything to v. what's wrong with this and what's the right solution?

Comment: You cannot assign value that way

Comment: You cannot have `v[i] = -1` within a list comprehension.

Comment: The part left of `for` must be an expression. An assignment is not an expression in Python.

Comment: `map` isn't supposed to change anything in the input. It creates a new map object (which you can convert to a list if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v[i] = -1` is not an expression (assignments are not expressions in Python), it's a statement, therefore it cannot be used in a generator expression like `(expr) for item in iterable`.

Use a normal `for` loop:

```py
for i in range(len(v)):
    if v[i] == 0:
        v[i] = -1
```

Comment: This can be done with a list comprehension by reassigning to `v`: `v = [-1 if e == 0 else e for e in v]`

Comment: @DeepSpace wasting O(n) memory for such a simple operation? Meh. Just awful IMHO.

Comment: what memory? `v` is already a defined list. No memory is wasted. If anything, `range` is wasting memory here

Comment: @DeepSpace you are creating a new list, and *then* assigning it to `v`. The "replacement" is not done in place (like in my solution). Therefore you are temporarily doubling the amount of used memory by doing this.

Comment: @DeepSpace premature optimization or not, I find that solution awful. It may look "pythonic", but it's not IMHO. You're free to post it as an answer though.

Comment: The question is if the original list should be modified or not. Depending on this a normal for loop must be used or a list comprehension can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
v = [-1 if x == 0 else x for x in v]
```